# Eclipse processing stopping when Gson is invoked

Tags: java, gson

I am having some problems with Gson. When the line in my code with Gson is reached,

```
Gson s = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

the processing stops completely. No error is thrown which is strange. I have tried gson 2.2 and 2.4. I am currently using JRE 1.6. Has anyone see this before?

Comment: Strange error like this usually cause by some dirty configuration. You may want to use a difference workspace and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out just adding the .jar file to eclipse was not enough. I needed to add it to the JSP website under web-inf/lib. This solved my problem.